# Looking for a TUI that can visualize CPU/RAM usage data captured by atop

Tags: cpu, monitoring, ram, atop

I've seed s-tui, and it is lovely, but is there something similar that can display usage data that was already captured into files?
I'm using atop to generate these files. If needed I'll switch to something else...